# Creating unique ID for features that are within polygons with unique IDs

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, overlapping-features, point-in-polygon, unique-id

I need to create and `"ID"` for items within a polygon that also takes into account the name of the polygon that the item is within, so what I need is something along the lines of: poly_X_Item 1-4, poly_Y_Item 1-4, poly_Z_Item 1-4.

I understand that I can use `@row_number` to create the `"ID"`s but its just adding the poly id to the field also that im having trouble with.

Comment: "Items" being what? Polygons, lines, points? Can you show a screenshot of what you have?

Comment: points. sorry my use of terminology might be a little off due to me being pretty new at all this. I cant really share screenshots or anything due to the somewhat sensitive nature of the project

Answer (score 5):

You can use an expression like the one that follows, concatenating four different elements using pipes (`||`) to "stick" them together: text-element `poly_` (line 1), the id of the polygon the points are within (line 2), the text element `_item_` (line 3) and the id of the point (line 4). Use this to create a new attribute with [field calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html?#using-the-field-calculator) (Replace `'polygon'` with the name of your polygon layer):

```
'poly_' || 
array_first ( overlay_within( 'polygon', $id)) || 
'_item_' || 
$id
```

This preserves the unique id (point item no.) of the points. If it should start from 1 for each polygon, the expression is a bit more complicated:

```
'poly_' || 
array_first ( overlay_within( 'polygon', $id)) || 
'_item_' || 
to_string (array_find (array_agg (array_first (overlay_within ('polygon', $id))||'_'||-$id,array_first (overlay_within ('polygon', $id))),array_first (overlay_within ('polygon', $id))||'_'||-$id)+1)
```

*Screenshot 1: the first expression used here directly in the label field that dynamically creates the label text:*
[image]

*Screenshot 2: the second expression, numbering the items from 1 in each polygon. The number of points per polygong is varying:*
[image]

**Edit**

For the problem rised in the comment, use this expression:

```
array_first ( overlay_within( 'distribution_area', $id)) || 
'-MST12-' || 
to_string (array_find (array_agg (array_first (overlay_within ('distribution_area', $id))||
-$id,array_first (overlay_within ('distribution_area', $id))),array_first (overlay_within ('distribution_area', $id))||-$id)+1)
```

Comment: That's absolutely fantastic thank you so much. The only thing I need to do now is work out how to have this in an actual field as opposed to just in the labels but thanks so much I wasn't even aware that the overlay within part was an option

Comment: Use field calculator with the exact same expression to generate it as attribute. Introducing it directly in the label was just for the screenshot/demonstration puropose.

Comment: I am once again using this expression to do the same thing however it is no longer increasing the count by 1 each time for the ID of the items any ideas why this may be?

My current expression is as follows:

'' || 
array_first ( overlay_within( 'distribution_area', "name")) || 
'-MST12-' || 
to_string (array_find (array_agg (array_first (overlay_within ('distribution_area', $id))||'_'||-$id,array_first (overlay_within ('disdtribution_area', $id))),array_first (overlay_within ('distribution_area', $id))||'_'||-$id)+1)